# Can't execute scripts on a mounted driver

Tags: mount, permissions, executable

When I want to execute some programs I get a message which say `Permission is denied`. The files are allowed to be executed, and I use `sudo`.

example:

```
# ./configure
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

what is the problem?

This is the `ls -l` on the directory:

```
  -pc:/media/H/gtimer-2.0.0$ ls -l
total 756
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  40052 Mar 27  2010 aclocal.m4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5483 Mar 27  2010 annotate.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    498 Mar 27  2010 AUTHORS
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14633 Mar 28  2010 ChangeLog
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4746 Mar 27  2010 changelog.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16690 Mar 28  2010 changelog.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   6392 Mar 27  2010 config.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   3249 Mar 27  2010 config.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 169973 Mar 27  2010 configure
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1340 Mar 27  2010 configure.ac
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1466 Mar 27  2010 configure.in
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8724 Mar 27  2010 confirm.c
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jul 31 06:10 contrib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17982 Mar 27  2010 COPYING
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21780 Mar 27  2010 custom-list.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2817 Mar 27  2010 custom-list.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17574 Mar 27  2010 depcomp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19068 Mar 27  2010 edit.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   3707 Mar 27  2010 FAQ.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9337 Mar 27  2010 gettext.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2547 Mar 27  2010 gtimer.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    144 Mar 27  2010 gtimer.desktop
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    242 Mar 27  2010 gtimer.doc-base
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4762 Mar 28  2010 gtimer.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1578 Mar 27  2010 gtimeri18n.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    158 Mar 27  2010 gtimer.install.in
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4230 Mar 27  2010 gtimer.xpm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18165 Mar 27  2010 http.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   3745 Mar 27  2010 http.h
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4096 Jul 31 06:10 icons
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7831 Mar 27  2010 INSTALL
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5598 Mar 27  2010 install-sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Mar 27  2010 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  94377 Mar 27  2010 main.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    767 Mar 27  2010 Makefile.am
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19189 Mar 27  2010 Makefile.in
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11135 Mar 27  2010 missing
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    722 Mar 27  2010 mkinstalldirs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 Mar 27  2010 NEWS
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4096 Jul 31 06:10 po
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10846 Mar 27  2010 project.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2111 Mar 27  2010 project.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   3010 Mar 27  2010 README
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  62715 Mar 27  2010 report.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5980 Mar 27  2010 requests
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2449 Mar 27  2010 rules
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19349 Mar 27  2010 task.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   3170 Mar 27  2010 task.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7679 Mar 27  2010 tcpt.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2528 Mar 27  2010 tcpt.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    627 Mar 27  2010 txt2h.pl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9678 Mar 27  2010 unhide.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   2561 Mar 27  2010 xextras.c
```

Comment: The output of `ls -l` please?

Comment: that's long. I should edit my post. But this folder is not the only case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute files on a mounted drive. Copy/Extract the content on your personal directory (or somewhere it isn't mounted), and it should work just fine.

This happens because your permissions are set at driver level, not at file/directory level.

You shouldn't even be able to extract a tar file on a mounted driver:

```
bt:/media/braiam/F66E431C6E42D551/src$ tar xzf llvm-3.3.src.tar.gz 
tar: llvm-3.3.src/.arcconfig: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: llvm-3.3.src/.gitignore: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: llvm-3.3.src/autoconf: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: llvm-3.3.src/autoconf: Cannot change mode to rwxr-xr-x: Operation not permitted
```